# How to run custom testNG runner with maven by jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng

I  am new to maven and Jenkins.. Plz help me with below requirements.

1.I have multiple test classes I.e tc001,tc002,tc003,tc004 etc..(using testng)

2.i am running these classes from a single runner class (similar to testNG.xml or this testNG .XML is written by code which includes all classes) , here I can manage which classes to run or which to not by controlling from external Excel file.

3.my question is can I run this scenario using maven and Jenkins?

4. Or can I run that testNG runner class using Jenkins.. Here I need to control which classes to be executed or which are not from external file.

Please suggest me the solution for this..

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>MobileTesting</groupId>
 <artifactId>com.maven</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>

 <name>com.maven</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 </properties>
 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <suiteXmlFiles>
      <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
     </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <fork>true</fork>
     <encoding>iso-8859-1</encoding>
     <source>1.8</source>
     <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>first-execution</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
                            <mainClass>com.demo.toolsqa.runner.TestCaseRunnerTestNG</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
              
  </plugins>
 </build>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>3.8.1</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
   <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
   <version>2.41.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.17</version>
  </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
   <version>3.15</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
   <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
   <version>6.10</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

</project>
```

[![

```html
my runner main class

/**
 * 
 */
package com.demo.toolsqa.runner;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.xml.XmlClass;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;
import org.testng.xml.XmlTest;

import com.beust.testng.TestNG;
import com.demo.toolsqa.tests.TC_001;
import com.demo.toolsqa.tests.TC_002;
import com.demo.toolsqa.tests.ToolsQARegistration;


/**
 * @author Afsar
 *
 */
public class TestCaseRunnerTestNG {

 public static List<XmlClass> getclassList(String TCName) {

  XmlClass classlist = null;
  switch (TCName) {

  case "LTI_ENV":
   classlist = new XmlClass(TC_001.class);
   break;
  case "LTQ_ENV":
   classlist = new XmlClass(TC_002.class);
   break;
  case "INT_ENV":
   classlist = new XmlClass(ToolsQARegistration.class);
   break;
  }

  List<XmlClass> class_list = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();
  class_list.add(classlist);
  return class_list;

 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XmlSuite mainsuite = new XmlSuite();
  mainsuite.setName("SmokeTest Suite");
  mainsuite.setFileName("SmokeTest.xml");
  mainsuite.setParallel("false");
  //mainsuite.addListener("utility.Listener");

  XmlTest mainTest;
  String sTestName="LTI_ENV";

    mainTest = new XmlTest(mainsuite);
    mainTest.setName("Test CaseName :" + sTestName);
    mainTest.setPreserveOrder("True");
    mainTest.setXmlClasses(getclassList(sTestName));
  
  //Reporter.log("total  number of TC included in test :"+ic-1);
  
  
  TestNG runner=new TestNG();
  List<XmlSuite>suites=new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
  suites.add(mainsuite);
  runner.setXmlSuites(suites);
  runner.run();  
 }

}

and testng.xml is 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.demo.toolsqa.tests.TC_002"/>
      <class name="com.demo.toolsqa.tests.TC_001"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYbbm.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYbbm.png)

Comment: No Test runner class necessary? Why using an Excel file ? Just run them all and you are sure everything works.. Furthermore just use the naming conventions depending in which phase you are running your tests (integration-test, test) ? maven-surefire-plugin or maven-failsafe-plugin...

Comment: @khmarbaise I wanted to run test cases in controlled manner like which test cases to be executed or not using external file..

Answer (score 0):

Following are two plugins which can be used in `pom.xml` to mention path of testng xml and runner/launcher class respectively.

**Plugin for including "TestNG.xml" file:-**

```
<build>
  <plugins>    
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
           <configuration>
               <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
               </suiteXmlFiles>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

**Plugin for including "Main Class" file:-**

```
     <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <encoding>iso-8859-1</encoding>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>first-execution</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
                            <mainClass>com.selenium.common.Launcher</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Jenkins configuration could be set as:

**Build:**

Root POM: ***pom.xml***

Goals and options: ***clean install***

Let me know if you face any issues. Thanks !

Comment: Thanks a lot Sameer !! I will let you know after implementing this plugins configuration in my project..

Comment: Hi Sameer, i have tried this but getting below error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.demo.toolsqa.runner.TestCaseRunnerTestNG" am attaching mt pom.xml in the above .

Comment: @Afsar: Does your `TestCaseRunnerTestNG` class contains `main` method ?
Also have you mentioned `sourceDirectory` in POM? And is your `TestCaseRunnerTestNG` class present in same directory ?

Comment: Hi Sameer, yes it contains main method ..Code attached... But I think I am not including class path in pom. Xml.... As am new to maven.. Could you please help me

Comment: You can choose either option. Either Include TestNG as suggested in #1 where you will not require main class or declare main class with package as suggested in #2 where main class will read TestNG xml and execute the scripts.

I would suggest you to try option #2 with `mainClass` node value as `com.demo.toolsqa.runner.TestCaseRunnerTestNG`.

Comment: If you face any exception while execution, do mention the exception and stacktrace. Thanks !